# List view difference in python

Tags: python, list

I am working on python project for my python course project so I need to get number from users so [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8jMp.png)

here is my test codes but the output is like that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRDB.png)

I want to store my input data like this one [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRDB.png)] not like this ['2'] what can I do for solve this.
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```py
yinp = int(input('enter your number'))
```

**Explanation:** By default python will take the inputs as `string`, you need to convert it to required type. In this case you need to convert into `integer`, `int()` is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

by declaring new variable as input and without declaring what type it is, python will adress the variable as `string`.
you will need to convert your variable:

`yinp= int(input("enter your number")`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the program doesn't know that you meant for "2" to be a number, you have to cast it into a number aka `int`, or a `float`.
You can do this like that (assuming there is only one input number):

```py
ydata.append(float(yinp))
```

Also learn how to paste code into Stackoverflow